# how to define exponential expression for a set in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I want to use the expression `2^P(I)` in `GAMS`. I tried the following:

`PFUN.. P(I) =e=(2**P(I));`

But I always get an **error 149**: `Uncontrolled set entered as constant`.

Can anyone help me to define that expression properly in `GAMS`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share this possible solution here maybe it can help other people. To define the exponential I used the following expression:

> P.l('i1')=2**P.l('i1');
>
> P.l('i2')=2 **P.l('I2');

and it worked so far.